# Extend TextField to hold one decimal field and allow two digits after decimal point

Tags: java, javafx

Right now, my TextField does not accept entry from alphabetic characters.

But I want it to hold currencies.

How do I extend it to hold one decimal point (i.e. `.`), and only allow two digits after the decimal point?

```
  foodPrice.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
            foodPrice.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
        }
    });
```

Comment: You sould have a look on [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html). Seems more appropriate. 
About the regex, you should try something like `^\d*(\.\d{2})?`.

Comment: @Pagbo You don't need to match the boundaries, if you're using `String.matches`. Also "only allow 2 digits" probably means up to 2 digits. Also the user need be allowed to input the string character by character. The regex should be something like `\d*(\.\d{0,2})?`